# Approximating probability of Cumulative Sum of random variables samples from Uniform[-1,1]

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Here is the question:

For $n = 25$ and $50$, approximate the probability $P(max_{1 \leq k \leq n}  S_k > 2\sqrt n)$ when the sample observations are iid $U[−1, 1]$, where $S_k= X_1 + X_2+...+X_k$.

I understand that it wants us to approximate the probability that the maximum cumulative sum of the $X_i$s is greater than $2\sqrt n$.  So, I created a code in R to run the simulation 10000 times and the probability turns out to be very small (i.e 5e-04, 3e-04).

However, I am stuck on how this can be shown by hand. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I also found this theorem in my book that might be related but I am not sure because it has n going to infinity:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(max_{1 \leq k \leq n}  S_k \leq x\sqrt n) = G(x), \text{ where } G(x)= 2\Phi(x)-1. $$